# How to specify silent/quiet in .gdbinit

Tags: gdb

> You can run gdb without printing the front material, which describes
>   gdb's non-warranty, by specifying --silent (or -q/--quiet):

Is there an option in `.gdbinit` to do the same as `gdb -q`?

I do not mind seeing important warranty stuff, but not each time I start gdb. I know I can use alias, but I am curious about the config file.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html

I looked into website documentation, read the man page, but cannot see if that is possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was curious about this, so I looked at the source.  There is no way to do it.

First, this relies on a local variable in the argument parsing function (`captured_main`).  Second, the message is printed before `~/.gdbinit` is read.

Aside from an alias (as you mentioned), the only other way to do this would be to modify gdb.

Answer (score 19):

The `startup-quietly` option was recently added to the 11.x branch of GDB ([Release notes](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=gdb-11.1-release)).

From the docs:

> `set startup-quietly on|off`
>
> `show startup-quietly`
>
> When 'on', this causes GDB to act as if "-silent" were passed on the
> command line.  This command needs to be added to an early
> initialization file (e.g. ~/.config/gdb/gdbearlyinit) in order to
> affect GDB.

Comment: This option has to be added to `.gdbearlyinit` file, not to `.gdbinit`.

Answer (score 12):

only way to keep your sanity if you are starting gdb a dozen times in a row is:

`alias gdb='gdb -q'`